# Rails cocoon f.fields_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm working with a project that requires nested forms to add multiple valves to a single order (order is called rfq in this case).

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Rfq::Valf):
    48:   </div>
    49:
    50:   <div id="valves">
    51:     <%= f.fields_for :valves do |valve| %>
    52:       <%= render 'valve_fields', f: valve %>
    53:     <% end %>
    54:       <%= link_to_add_association 'add valve', f, :valves %>
```

Here's relevant part of the form partial,

```
<%= form_for @rfq do |f| %>
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :application %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :application %>
  </div>

  <div id="valves">
    <%= f.fields_for :valves do |valve| %>
      <%= render 'valve_fields', f: valve %>
    <% end %>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add valve', f, :valves %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Valve fields partial:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :line %>
        <%= f.text_field :productline %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove valve", f %>
</div>
```

RFQ model:

```
class Rfq < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :valves
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :valves, :allow_destroy => true
    belongs_to :customer
    has_paper_trail
end
```

Valve model:

```
class Valve < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :rfq
    has_paper_trail
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your `_valve_fields.html.erb` file.

Comment: @jljohnstone added fields, partial.

Comment: I don't see anything here that is obviously wrong. Post your RFQ and Valve models if you can.

Comment: @jljohnstone I just added both models, thanks for the help, it's both comforting and nerve-wracking when someone else doesn't see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying your "Valve" class name as illustrated below.

```
class Rfq < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valves, :class_name => "Valve"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :valves, :allow_destroy => true
  belongs_to :customer
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Comment: That solved my initial problem but now i have this one,

Missing partial rfqs/_valf_fields, application/_valf_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/CRM_dev/rqm3/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"

it looks like it changed valve to valf for some reason

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and make this a separate question, thanks for the help!

Comment: This traces back to how Rails figures out what the singular form of words are. In this case, it's using "valf" as the singular form of "valves" which isn't really what you want. Take a look at the [inflector documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) to see how to correct this.